# Graph Clustering Tool

Tags: graph, cluster-analysis, data-mining, collaborative-filtering

I've build a collabrative filtering algorithm (cosine, item-item) to reveal relationships between items. In the end my result data looks like this,

```
itemNo relatedItemNo    similarityValue
1546301 1543903 0.10767638
1546301 1530836 0.093250481
1546301 1479721 0.10767638
1557616 1573636 0.121267813
1557616 1558024 0.161690417
1086551 1437760 0.127000127
1086551 1552321 0.083333333
1086551 1578137 0.127000127
1086551 1560842 0.081110711
....... ....... ...........
```

Now i want to do clustering with it. Using the similarity values between items i want to get some clusters saying 1546301, 1479721,1543903 is in cluster A; 1086551,1552321, 1560842  is in cluster B.

How can i manage this? Im new to data mining so its hard to use even simple tools.

I learned this is called Graph Clustering and Ive downloaded igraph for r, install cluto and try some steps but i didnt even understand the input data format of them.

Can you show me the way? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The subject of graph clustering is vast and there are a lot of different approaches, each with its own special details. For an extensive treatment on the subject, please see [this review](http://www.leonidzhukov.net/hse/2015/networks/papers/GraphClustering_Schaeffer07.pdf).

But, if you are looking for something to get you started and based on the description provided so far, you could try to identify clusters via the use of [Centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality). Specifically, [betweenness centrality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Centrality#Betweenness_centrality) (as defined for **vertices**) would provide an opportunity to sort the vertices of the graph (representing items) by order of most commonly preferred items (assuming that your similarity refers to [something like this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slope_One#Item-based_collaborative_filtering_of_purchase_statistics)).

Doing this in Python is a matter of a few lines with [Networkx](https://networkx.github.io/)

```
import networkx
G = networkx.read_edgelist("myfile.csv", delimiter="\t") #Assuming that your file is tab separated here. If it is coma separated then substitute \t for a ,. Also, it would be good to get rid of the header (i.e. the first line of the CSV.
bc = networkx.betweenness_centrality(G)
```

Variable `bc` now holds the betweenness centrality of each node. To sort that one in reverse order (and therefore get your cluster "hubs" first), you could simply `bc_sorted = sorted(bc.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)`

You can use the above as a template for "translating" the code to another language, e.g. R. In fact, there is the equivalent Python package ([igraph](http://igraph.org/python/)) which does have a [betweenness centrality](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#betweenness) metric for nodes already implemented as well as a [Read_Edgelist](http://igraph.org/python/doc/igraph.GraphBase-class.html#Read_Edgelist) which will enable you to read your data off the disk. That is, the equivalent R code to get you started is not vastly different than these three lines.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer. I installed python and networkx. But cant manage to get a result. I'll add my data view and the error message. I cant understand why it says it cannot covert nodes 1,2 to type int. http://arge.kariyer.net/images/test/Capture.PNG and http://arge.kariyer.net/images/test/Capture2.PNG do you have any idea?

Comment: Sorry to hear that, thanks for sharing the errors, having had a look at them, I do not think that they are "show stoppers". So, can I please ask you to `G = networkx.read_edgelist("evet.csv", delimiter=",")`. Which implies that you re-save your CSV as a comma separated rather than space separated file.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it didnt change as you can see here http://arge.kariyer.net/images/test/Capture3.PNG . Im using visual studio as IDE. Could it be relevant? Any more idea?

Comment: I would not blame it on Visual Studio just yet :). Can you please try removing the edgetype and nodetype parameters?

Comment: I tried all the combination then i reach a stage with no error but no meaningful result either http://arge.kariyer.net/images/test/Capture5.PNG   :). Then i found and tried "read_weighted_edgelist" and got some result but im not sure if its the answer i seek. It does not seem meaningful to me. and  http://arge.kariyer.net/images/test/Capture4.PNG

Comment: Yes, that is the expected output. Nodes with high betweenness centrality are the hubs of the clusters. Good point about the read_weighted_edgelist.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts. I cant give up vote right now but i'll do as soon as i can :). But it didnt satisfy me still. I thought the result ll be as clear as, 101,104,140 in Cluster A -- 144, 243, 125 in Cluster B and so on.. How can i get that kind of result or am i missing a core point about graph clustering?

Comment: No problem, I would be glad if it helped you fully. My understanding was that you wanted to somehow identify the clusters. There is much more information in section 5.4.4 in the paper that I link in my response. All the best